# My iCloud Drive in Preview is empty where are my files?

Tags: icloud

When I open Finder and click the "iCloud Drive" on left side it doesn't show any files. There are files but I have lost the link.

Comment: To clarify - you're describing the Preview app in the subject line, but then talking about Finder in the body of the question. If you're in Preview, look on the left side and make sure to click iCloud Drive (and not just "Preview) on the left side, and you should see a variety of options. htmlcat's answer below will help if you have somehow accidentally turned things off. Additionally if you just turned things on it will take a long time for a large set of files to sync to your computer. So be patient.

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that there is no "iCloud Drive" in the sidebar, or that no files are showing up in it?

-If it's the first one, then you can re-add it by going to Finder > Preferences, clicking on "Sidebar," then clicking the checkmark next to "iCloud Drive."

-If it's the second, then you might have accidentally unchecked "iCloud Drive" in the "iCloud" icon on System Preferences. If you're on Catalina, you have to click "Apple ID" at the top of System Preferences instead, then "iCloud" on the left.